# Mass Delete All Files starting with “DirsToDelete” using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, delete-file

I have a directory called Somedir.
I then add 5 files called DirsToDelete 1, DirsToDelete 1 – Copy, DirsToDelete (2)..etc,,,
They are all identically named except for digits at end or - Copy

I want to delete files with "DirsToDelete"

I have tried the following-

```
D1 ='DirsToDelete'
for filename in glob.glob("C:/Somedir"):
    os.remove(D1)

PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:/Somedir'
```

I have also tried running Cmd commands from python including –

```
FOR /D /R %%X IN (C:\Somedir\DirsToDelete) DO RD /S /Q "%%X"
```

This works overkill deleting crucial files.

```
FOR /D /R %%X IN (C:\Somedir\DirsToDelete) DO RD /S /Q "%%X"
```

The works but deletes crucial files.

Maybe

```
del /s C:\*’DirsToDelete’
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be done:

```
import glob
path = "/home/mydir/Somedir*"
for filename in glob.glob(path):
    os.remove(filename)
```

Though as per the permission issues. Run the script as the administrator if you dont have rights to delete. **However make sure what you really want to delete** since C drive has critical files.